# Text block near image

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing, vertical-alignment

I'm creating a photo address book for the community. Near the photo there are 3 text blocks 1. Names, 2. Address/phone/email and 3. native place). I want each of this blocks to be at top, center and bottom respectively.

When I use every node `anchor = center`, there is equal space at and bottom of the text. But if the space is between the text blocks then it would be great.

[image]

Excerpt of the `tex` file is below:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a5paper]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx,pdfpages}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{scalefnt}
\usepackage[top=15mm, bottom=15mm, left=10mm, right=10mm]{geometry}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes.geometric,%
  decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.pathmorphing,shapes,%
  matrix,shapes.symbols,decorations.markings,shadows}

\pagestyle{plain}
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{+5mm}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-5mm}
\begin{document}
%\includepdfmerge{/home/chidamba/Downloads/51_nov26.pdf,-}
\setcounter{page}{3}
\scalefont{0.9}

\begin{tikzpicture}
[every node/.style={anchor=north}]
\matrix [fill={rgb:black,1;white,8}] (profile1)
{
\node [text width=44mm] {
Xxxxxxx Xxxxxxxx \\
\vspace{2ex}
\begin{raggedleft}
Xxxxxxxxx, XX 99999 \\
\vspace{2ex}
xxxxxxx@xxxxx.xxx \\
\end{raggedleft}
\vspace{2ex}
Xxxxxxxxx \\
Xxxxxxxxxxxxxx Xxxxx \\
(Xxxxxxxxxxxx) \\
}; &&
\node { 
\includegraphics[width=70mm,height=50mm,keepaspectratio]{\detokenize{/home/chidamba/Downloads/pn_photos/Chettinad_house.jpg}}
}; \\ 
};

\matrix [fill=blue!15,below=2mm] at (profile1.south) (profile2)
{
\node { 
\includegraphics[width=70mm,height=50mm,keepaspectratio]{\detokenize{/home/chidamba/Downloads/pn_photos/Chettinad_house.jpg}}
}; && 
\node [text width=44mm] {
\begin{raggedleft}
Xxxxxx Xxxxxxxxx \\
Xxxxx Xxxxxx \\
Xxxxxxxxxxx Xxxxxx Xx \\
Xxxxxx Xxxxxxxx Xxxxxx \\
Xxxxxxxxx Xxxxx \\
\end{raggedleft}
\vspace{2ex}
9999 Xxxxx Xxxxx \\
Xxxxxxxxxx, XX 99999 \\
\vspace{2ex}
(999) 999-9999 \\
xxxxxxx@xx.xxxxxxxxxxx.xxx \\
xxxxx.xxxxxx@xxxxx.xxx \\
\vspace{2ex}
\begin{raggedleft}
Xxxxxxxx \\
Xxxxxxxx Xxxxx \\
\end{raggedleft}
}; \\
};

\matrix [fill={rgb:black,1;white,8},below=2mm] at (profile2.south) (profile3)
{
\node [text width=44mm] {
Xxxxxx Xxxxxxxxxxxxxx \\
Xxxxxx Xxxxxx \\
Xxxxx \\
\vspace{2ex}
\begin{raggedleft}
99999 Xxxxxxxx Xxxxxxx \\
Xxxxxxxxx, XX 99999 \\
\vspace{2ex}
(999) 999-9999 \\
xxxxxx\_xxxxxx@xxxxx.xxx \\
xxxxxxxxxxxx@xxxxxxx.xxx \\
\end{raggedleft}
\vspace{2ex}
Xxxxxxxxx \\
Xxxxxxxxx Xxxxx \\
}; &&
\node { 
\includegraphics[width=70mm,height=50mm,keepaspectratio]{\detokenize{/home/chidamba/Downloads/pn_photos/Chettinad_house.jpg}}
}; \\ 
};

\end{tikzpicture}
\newpage
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).  Thanks for including a complete document, but can you also make it compilable?

Comment: I use pdflatex on linux mint to create the pdf for this document. I don't know how to make it compilable, I'll look into it.

Comment: If you add a dummy example of the layout you're trying to achieve, you might get a better strategy pointed out too. It's my experience on Tex.SX that there's usually a better general way of doing things that we normally miss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a macro version of the type of alignment you are looking for:

[image]

With this approach, the names block at the top will stay at the top and grow downward as you add more names, the address block grows from the center of the image, and the bottom block grows upwards are you add more lines.

### Further Enhancements

- You could define another macro to place the text on the right side as well.
  Personally, I would use [the `xparse` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse) to define a starred variant `\AddImage*` which places the text on the right.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background layer} 
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground layer} 
\pgfsetlayers{background layer,main,foreground layer}

\newcommand{\AddImage}[5][]{%
    % #1 = options for bounding box
    % #2 = \includegraphics command for image
    % #3 = Names
    % #4 = Address
    % #5 = Other Text
    %
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{foreground layer}% default
    \node [inner sep=0pt] (MyPictureNode) {#2};
    \node [anchor=north east, align=right] at (MyPictureNode.north west) {#3};
    \node [anchor=east, align=right] at (MyPictureNode.west) {#4};
    \node [anchor=south east, align=right] at (MyPictureNode.south west) {#5};
    \end{pgfonlayer}
    %
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background layer}
    \draw [fill=gray!20, draw=brown, thick, #1]
        ([shift={(-3pt,-3pt)}]current bounding box.south west) rectangle 
        ([shift={( 3pt, 3pt)}]current bounding box.north east);
    \end{pgfonlayer}
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{document}
\AddImage
    {\includegraphics[width=70mm,height=50mm,keepaspectratio]{../images/EiffelWide.jpg}}
    {Name 1 \\ Name 2 \\ Name 3}
    {123 Main Street \\ Anytown, Country \\ Phone}
    {Some Text \\ More Text}

\AddImage[draw=blue, ultra thick, fill=red!25]
    {\includegraphics[width=70mm,height=50mm,keepaspectratio]{../images/EiffelWide.jpg}}
    {Name 1 \\ Name 2 \\ Name 3}
    {123 Main Street \\ Anytown, Country \\ Phone}
    {Some Text \\ More Text}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Haha, our answers are pretty much the same thing. That's an honour for me (given your rep) :)   ... Thanks for the edit, btw.

Comment: @recluze: Don't let my rep fool you into thinking I know what I am doing. :-) But I interpreted the question as wanting to position the text at the sides of the image.

Comment: Yes thank you very much, I want the text to be in the sides of the image. Is there a way to have bounding box for all these nodes. I have added a screenshot link.

Comment: You could use the `fit` library along with the `backgrounds` library for the box.

Comment: @user22587: Updated to draw a box around the bounding box.

Comment: @PeterGrill Is the definition of layers and the foreground layer really necessary? I've been using the `backgrounds` library without them (since I can just use the background layer directly), when I only need one bg layer.

Comment: Thank you very much Peter, I never thought I would get so many answers so quickly. Appreciate it.

Comment: @recluze: Yes you can probably get away without it, but I prefer to standardize and this method works for most of my needs.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using anchors with the `positioning` library. Personally, I think it makes for much cleaner code.

[image]

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}


\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={draw}]
  \node (name) {Name};
  \node [below=1em of name.south, anchor=north, minimum height=5em] (photo) {Image}; 
  \node [below=1em of photo.south, anchor=north] (info) {Other Info}; 
  \node [below=1em of info.south, anchor=north] (info two) {Other Info 2};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```