# Feature Page

Tags: environments

Lets say that I want to create a feature environment, which has two columns, in one column there is a picture (with a caption), in the second there is text. For the odd pages, I want the picture on the left, text on the right, and, for the even pages, I want the text on the left, picture on the right.

What is the best way to achieve this, Does someone have an example?

I have something working, using tikz, but the code is messy (lots of manual tweaking on a case-by-case basis). I am sure a cleaner example exists....

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [the `changepage`  package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/changepage) to detect if it is an odd or even page, and switch the order you place things:

[image]

### Notes:

- [Text block near image](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84414/text-block-near-image) shows how to use `tikz` to place text at the appropriate points relative to the image.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=9.0cm, margin=0.5cm]{geometry}% For better illustrative image
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{changepage}
\strictpagecheck

\newcommand*{\ImageSize}{3.5cm}%  Set the width of the images here

\newcommand*{\TextSize}{\dimexpr\linewidth-\ImageSize-4\tabcolsep}%
\newcommand{\MyTwoColumn}[2]{%
\medskip\par\noindent%
\centering\checkoddpage%
    \noindent
    \ifoddpage
        \begin{tabular}{m{\ImageSize}m{\TextSize}}\toprule
        \includegraphics[width=\ImageSize]{#1} &  {\raggedright#2\par} \\
    \else
        \begin{tabular}{m{\TextSize}m{\ImageSize}}\toprule
        {\raggedright#2\par} & \includegraphics[width=\ImageSize]{#1}\\
    \fi\bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
\medskip\par%
}

\begin{document}
\MyTwoColumn{../images/EiffelWide}{Awesome Vacation on left page}
\clearpage
\MyTwoColumn{../images/EiffelWide}{Awesome Vacation on right page}
\end{document}
```

Comment: the picture on the right in the graphic is indented more from the edge than the one on the left.  better if the spacing is a mirror image.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Good point. Have updated solution.